# Django-ratings CommandError for models

Tags: python, django, django-ratings

i installed an app django-ratings. I want to syncdb, but here is my error:

```
djangoratings.vote: 'user' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User',
which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
```

Iam using AllAuth for Facebook login, and custom user auth with some extra features.

In settings file i provide

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accountext.User'
```

How to fix that error from djangoratings?

Thanx

Comment: make sure `accountext` is in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: accountext is in INSTALLED_APPS :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an open `django-ratings` issue: [Complete Django 1.5 Custom User Model compatibility](https://github.com/dcramer/django-ratings/pull/44). `django-ratings` was made before the custom user model was implemented. It [uses `auth.User` model directly](https://github.com/dcramer/django-ratings/blob/master/djangoratings/models.py#L6) instead of going through dynamic `AUTH_USER_MODEL` settings.

`django-ratings` is not actively maintained, pull requests are in opened state for years. I would consider not using it.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for that type of answer but no luck. 

Do you know any other alternatives? Django-simple-ratings does not work too.

Comment: @juree there is also [`django-generic-ratings`](https://bitbucket.org/frankban/django-generic-ratings) but it looks like it has the same problem. Well, `Django-simple-ratings` is more actively developed, consider [filing an issue](https://github.com/django-de/django-simple-ratings).